# Unable to access the cookies from request headers

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, svelte, sveltekit

```
    const headers = event.request.headers
    console.log('headers: ', headers)
    console.log('type is ', typeof headers) 
    console.log('keys are ', Object.keys(headers))
    console.log('cookie are ', headers.cookie)
```

**Output:**

```
headers:  {
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  cookie: 'userid=7599271f-87de-4f44-8625-5d4dc4af4069; authToken=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6ImNsMWl4d2Y2aTAwMTdmNzNlcnVweWhqY3UiLCJpYXQiOjE2NDk1MTIzMjB9.ltrLZV7aFeNCmCtC5ZMVZvRhM5c285TAEWf_zFbVGs0',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'if-none-match': '"1l79fw0"',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/profile',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-gpc': '1',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.45 Safari/537.36'
}
```

```
type is object
keys are  []
cookie are  undefined
```

[Click here to see my code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypS5z.png)

Can anyone say what's wrong with it?

Comment: I would guess that "headers" is a [Header object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers).  To read a property try headers.get("cookie")

Answer (score 0):

It should be `event.request.headers.get(“cookie”)`